# Xlib error BadValue when pressing altright or AltGr using python pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

I get this error when I write { with pyautogui.

I need to press AltGr or altright + '

I get this error:

```
 pyautogui.press('altright')

 X protocol error:
  <class 'Xlib.error.BadValue'>: code = 2, resource_id = 0, sequence_number = 16,major_opcode = 132, minor_opcode = 2
 X protocol error:
 <class 'Xlib.error.BadValue'>: code = 2, resource_id = 0, sequence_number = 18, major_opcode = 132, minor_opcode = 2
```

even when I press

pyautogui.hotkey("altright", "'", interval=0.1)

same results

thank you.

Comment: I had the same problem. On a raspberry pi I solved it using pypeclip package to copy the string to clipnoard and use pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v') to paste ist. but on a regular computer running ubuntu that will not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution that's working for me now.
I used pynput instead of pyautogui to type keyboard strokes. It seems that pyautogui has still some issues with different keyboard layouts.

I created a function to siply write a string with an interval between the key strokes (like in pyautogui):

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
from time import sleep

def write(txt=None):
    if isinstance(txt, str):

        kb = Controller()

        for c in txt:
            kb.type(c)
            sleep(0.05)
```

pynput seems to be available for python2.7 as well as python3 via pip.

You can also use the press function to press a specific key altright is used the internal Key name alt-right or alt-gr (depending on you keyboard layout). See the examples you can google the see the other functions. there's also a demo listener script out there, to get the names of the keys you pressed.